# Changing the value of range during iteration in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, range, iteration

```
>>> k = 8
>>> for i in range(k):
        print i
        k -= 3
        print k
```

Above the is the code which prints numbers from `0-7` if I use just `print i` in the for loop.

I want to understand the above code how it is working, and is there any way we can update the value of variable used in `range(variable)` so it iterates differently.

Also why it always iterates up to the initial `k` value, why the value doesn't updated.

I know it's a silly question, but all ideas and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't change the range after it's been generated. In Python 2, `range(k)` will make a list of integers from 0 to k, like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Changing `k` after the list has been made will do nothing.

If you want to change the number to iterate to, you could use a while loop, like this:

```
k = 8
i = 0
while i < k:
    print i
    k -= 3
    i += 1
```

Comment: Adding on: In Python 3, `range` is a sequence itself, it doesn't make a `list`, but it's still based on the value of `k` at the time it was constructed, with subsequent modifications to `k` making no difference to the `range` object.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `range(k)` is evaluated just *once*, not on every iteration. You can't set `k` and expect the `range(k)` result to change, no. From the [`for` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> The expression list is evaluated once; it should yield an iterable object.

You can use a `while` loop instead:

```
i = 0
k = 8
while i < k:
    print i
    i += 1
    k -= 3
```

A `while` loop does re-evaluate the test each iteration. Referencing the [`while` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement):

> This repeatedly tests the expression and, if it is true, executes the first suite

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to change k and affect the loop you need to make sure you are iterating over mutable object. For example:

```
k = list(range(8))
for i in k:
        print(i)
        k.pop()
        k.pop()
        k.pop()
        print(k)
```

Or alternatively:

```
k = list(range(8))
for i in k:
        print(i)
        k[:] = k[:-3]
        print(k)
```

Both will result with

```
0
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1
[0, 1]
```

Comment: thanks, I already tried this. This was the first thing after i figured out that we cannot change the value of range function again.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this ,I think, but I dont know if this is what you want.

```
def to_infinity():
index = 0
while True:
    yield index
    index += 1

for i in to_infinity():
    print(i)
```