# is the i under a for loop statement different from the i in 'for i in range()'?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, I have a question with the below code:

```
for i in range(50):

    i += 201

    print(i)
```

the code is started from `i=0`,and after statement `i += 201`. `i` should be equal 201. But why the loop still continue? 201 should be out of `range(50)`. Does that means the `i` in the `for i in range(50)` is different from the `i` in `i += 201`?

```
for i in range(50):
    i += 201
    print(i)
```

I expect the loop interrupt but it continued to print from 201 to 250.

Comment: Here is already an answer to your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672963/changing-the-value-of-range-during-iteration-in-python.

Comment: Also please edit your question. The code is not displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

when you loop through a range it will give you the next value in the range, not check for the current i value.

So while you can change `i` inside the loop, the value it will have next is the next value `range(50)` will give it.

What you want is probably a `while` loop where you can have a condition