# how can i control the iteration of the for loop in python

Tags: python, c++, loops

I am coming from a c++ language and there if i change the value of 'i' in the loop then it affect the iteration of the loop but it is not happening in python.

for example, in c++:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    cout<<i<<" ";
    if(i==5)
        i = 8;
}
```

in above code, as the value of 'i' reaches 5 it become 8 and after one more iteration it become 9 and then loop ends.
output of the above code is-

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 9
```

but when i write the similar code in python it doesn't affect the iteration and the loop runs all 10 times.
code in python is -

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i == 5:
        i = 8
    print(i, end=" ")
```

the output of this code is -

```
0 1 2 3 4 8 6 7 8 9
```

it is just changing the value of 5 to 8, and not changing the loop iteration.

how can i achieve the c++ result in python, please help!
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: You can always `continue` for `i` value between 6 to 8 like `if 5 < i < 9: continue`

Comment: This seems to be the same questions as [Changing the value of range during iteration in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672963/changing-the-value-of-range-during-iteration-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `i in range(0,10)` you are generating a list of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` that you are later on iterating over, this means that the value of `i` is not used as an increasing int but you are rather iterating over an array.

The best solution would probably be to change from a for loop to a while loop instead.

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if i == 5:
        i = 8
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a while loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if i == 6:
        i = 9
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 9
```